# Discriminant of $R^2 \rightarrow R^2$ map

Tags: polynomials, discriminant, singularity-theory

I want to calculate the discriminant set of a function (germ) $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ based on the $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ example of [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/2202.05825). The function is defined as
\begin{equation}
f(x,y) = \begin{pmatrix} x^2 - y^2 \\ 2 x y \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
with $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$. This function defines a vector field around the origin of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and the vector field itself winds around the origin twice.
One can define a perturbation of this function by introducing the following so-called unfolding $f_{\mathbf{t}}$
\begin{equation}
f_{\mathbf{t}}  = \begin{pmatrix} x^2 - y^2 \\ 2 x y \end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} t_1 x + t_2 y \\ t_3 x + t_4 y\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} t_5 \\ t_6\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
where $t_i \in \mathbb{R}$ and they are assumed to be small $t_i \ll 1$. We can characterize the unfolding of $f$ by a vector $\mathbf{t} \in \mathbb{R}^6$, $\mathbf{t} = (t_1, t_2, t_3, t_4, t_5, t_6)$. For some points in this $\mathbb{R}^6$ the above unfolding have 2 points for which $f_{\mathbf{t}}(x,y) = 0$, while for some other points of $\mathbb{R}^6$ there are  4 such points where $f_{\mathbf{t}}$ vanishes.

What I am interested in is the boundary of these regions around the origin. This boundary is called the discriminant set (or set-germ in my case).

A similar scenario can be seen on Fig.2 of the cited article, where the function is a simple $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ mapping and the unfolding is defined by two parameters only :
\begin{equation}
f_\mathbf{t} = x^3 + p x + q
\end{equation}
with $\mathbf{t} = (p,q)$.

I know the definition of the discriminant set: 
*Def*: The discriminant set of $f$ is the set of those points $\mathbf{t} \in \mathbb{R}^6$ (in our case) for which $\exists (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 $ such that
$f_\mathbf{t}(x,y) = 0$ and the determinant of the Jacobian of the function $g(x,y,\mathbf{t}) = (f_\mathbf{t}(x,y), \mathbf{t}) $ vanishes.
In the above definition the function $g$ is defined to be a $\mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R}^6 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^8$ mapping such that for each $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbf{t} \in \mathbb{R}^6$ is mapped to $(f_{\mathbf{t},1}(x,y),f_{\mathbf{t},2}(x,y), t_1, t_2, t_3,t_4,t_5,t_6)$ and $f_{\mathbf{t},j}$ denotes the $j$-th component of the unfolding $f_\mathbf{t}$.

I have worked on the algebra and the constraint that characterize the discriminant set seem to be unsolvable.
Any suggestions on how to tackle such a problem without dealing with the equations themselves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Much simplification occurs if we use complex notation from the outset. The unperturbed map $(x,y)\to (x^2-y^2, 2x y)$  can be written in complex notation as $z=x+iy\to w= u+iv=z^2$. The perturbation to this map is a general affine map from the $z$ plane to the $w$ plane, and this perturbing map can be written as
$ z\to w=Az + B\overline z -C$

where $(A,B,C)$ are three arbitrary complex "control parameters" , which are the arbitrary constants in the unfolding space.These are equivalent to 6 real control parameters. (Note that the presence of $\overline z$ indicates that the typical linear perturbation is not holomorphic (aka not analytic.) (The analysis of complex-valued mappings that are built with such terms that are not analytic is an extension of classical 19th century complex analysis that has been developed extensively in the last century but is generally not discussed in the undergraduate curriculum. The book by Krantz cited below is a good introduction to the modern theory.)   Thus the full expression for the fully  perturbed map can be written in complex notation as

$z\to w=z^2 + A z+ B \overline z -C$.

My belief  is that you want to understand under what circumstances the solutions of the perturbed equation $w(z)=0$ abruptly change character  as we perturb the control parameters in unfolding space.
This transition occurs when what were formerly two distinct roots appear to merge into a single  solution of higher multiplicity (repeated root)
If that interpretation is correct, then here is the next step.
The equation $w=0$ means $ z^2 + Az + B\overline z=C$. Thus we can regard the relation $C= f(z)=z^2+ A z+ B\overline z$ as a map from the $z$ plane to the $C$ plane, and we want to see for which values of $A$ and $B$ there occurs a solution of multiplicity two or more in the $z$ plane. (One can also regard this as a situation in which the inverse function theorem breaks down: there fails to be a simple smoothly-varying local 1-1 way to assign exactly one single solution $z$ to a known value of $C$ because two solutions pinch together.) The inverse function theorem fails when the Jacobian of the map $z\to C$ is zero. In other words, the mapping $z\to C$ has a critical point.

So we need to find the critical points of $f$ in the $z$ plane, and then compute their image under the map $C=f(z)$.
Henceforth we will occasionally write the map $C=f(z)$ instead  as $w=f(z)$ since that is more traditional notation when analyzing complex-valued mappings.

**The critical points.**
The Jacobian  degenerates (i.e., the map $z\to w$ has a critical point as a function of $z$) when the differential  $dz\to dw= (2 z+A) dz + B \ d \overline z$ has nontrivial kernel.  Writing the nonzero element in the kernel as $dz= r e^{\theta}$  we see after some algebra (cancelling $r$) that this requires $ (2z+A) e^{i\theta} + B e^{-i\theta}=0$.  Solutions exist iff $2z+A =-B e^{-2 i \theta}$ where $\theta$ is arbitrary.  Thus we can parametrize the critical points in the $z$ plane nicely as $ z= \frac{-1}{2} [ A+ B e^{-2 i \theta}]$.  As we vary the variable $\tau=-2\theta$ this parametrizes a circle in the $z$ plane centered at $z=-A/2$  of radius $|B|/2$. Denote this  critical circle  in the $z$ plane by $\Gamma =\Gamma (A,B)$.  (Below we will assume it is parametrized as a function of $\tau=-2 \theta$.)

**The critical values of $f$.**
Treating $C$ as a function of $z$ and the controls $A,B$, the critical values of $C$ are just the  values obtained by evaluating the function $C= f( z: A,B)$ when $ z= \frac{-1}{2} [ A+ B e^{-2 i \theta}]$ lies on the critical circle $\Gamma$ determined by $A$ and $B$. Thus you are led to consider the subset of control space  consisting of all points of the form $ (A,B,C)= (A,B, f(z, A,B)$ evaluated at all values of  $z\in \Gamma(A,B)$, parametrized as a function of $\tau$.

One can see that as a function of $\tau=2\theta$, $C$ is a complex Fourier series.  The various complex amplitudes are certain explicit linear and quadratic terms in $A$ and $B$. In fact

$$C=-(A^2/4) - (\overline A B)/2 - 1/2 B \overline B e^{-i \tau} + 
 1/4 B^2 e^{2 i \tau}$$

The Fourier series $\tau \to C(\tau)$  traces a [deltoid curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deltoid_curve) that has three cusp points forming an equilateral triangle.  The cusps occur where $dC/d\tau=0$. Below is a plot of a typical example.

P.S. The corrected picture below now should match the parameter constants, as discussed in the comments sections.

[image]

P.P.S Ahlfors  has an introductory section (see p. 6 excerpted below) [Lectures on Quasiconformal maps](https://books.google.com/books?id=DKuTAwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false)
that has a nice geometric discussion of the significance of the terms in the complex expansions $dw= f_z dz+ f_{\overline z}  \overline  dz$ and he explicitly computes the Jacobian $J(f)$ in terms of these two parameters. (This notation for the terms in this expansion is sometimes attributed to Wirtinger.). He shows that the Jacobian vanishes precisely when $ |f_z|= | f_{\overline z}|$ which explains why the critical circle computed earlier is given by $|2z+A|= |B|$. [image]

Comment: I think the plot that you linked corresponds to a different set of parameters. I think it corresponds to the a = i, b = 2 choice instead of b = 2+i.

Comment: Can you provide some source for the assumption regarding what you claim to be the most general form of the perturbation?

Comment: Sorry this is one of those "obvious" facts that are hard to document. I tried searching standard textbook references such as Ahlfors Complex Analysis and Krantz&Greene Function Theory of One Complex Variable but AFAIK they did not deal explicitly with the case of linear maps in detail. Just try writing any pair of ordinary  real-variable linear equations $u= ax +b y, v= cx+dy$ using substitutions $x= (z + \overline z )/2$ and $ y= (z-\overline z)/(2i)$ and check that $f=u+iv $ takes the form $f= A z + B \overline z$ for complex constants $A$ and $B$ (and conversely...)

Comment: P.S. Krantz Chapter 1 discusses the case of polynomials with some examples.

Comment: Thanks for the extension of the answer and the source. It still remains a mystery for me, why we don't have a perturbation like D*z^3 in the perturbation. Why is it enough to consider first order terms only?

Comment: Great question! That could be done but sometimes arbitrary choices are made in order to keep a model simple. Also, if $D$ is large, then the model totally changes its structure and no longer looks like a small perturbation of a quadratic, which might not be physically plausible. Perhaps you can ask the authors what motivated their choices.

Comment: Also, if $D$ is small, then the cubic term can be absorbed inside the quadratic as $ z^2 + Dz^3 = (z+ e)^2  = z^2 + 2 ze +e^2$ where  we choose the expression $e$ as a power series in $z$ with undetermined coefficients that  begins $ e=  D z^2/2 +\ldots $ . Then the change of variables $\tilde z= z+e$ makes the problem look basically as before, just with new variables. This sort of trick can often be made rigorous and is known as the structural stability phenomenon for elementary catastrophes. Deep work initiated by Rene Thom provides the rigor.

Comment: See this overview https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catastrophe_theory

Comment: A nice reference is Arnold's book: Singularities of Differentiable Maps, Volume 1, Part 1, Chapter 1.8, where he investigates the same mapping and gives a detailed analysis.